# How to add a column with a filter in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I currently have the following table:

[image]

then I find the ranking, which will vary with a filter. The rankig I calculate is like this:

first I create the column uniqueRank, which will have for tiebrakes

[image]

to then calculate in a measure the ranking that will present a filter

[image]

Quizás quisiste decir: entonces calcular la medida para poder sectorizar en 4, de lasiguiente manera
76/5000
then I calculate the measure to be able to sectorize in 4, of the following way:

```
cuartil = 
  IF(tabla_ranking[ranking2]<= 
 [total_registros]*0.25;"1P";IF(tabla_ranking[ranking2]<= 
 [total_registros]*0.5;"2P";IF(tabla_ranking[ranking2]<= 
 [total_registros]*0.75;"3P";"4P")))
```

and it shows me that

[image]

the detail is that I do not want to show it in that table, but in a graph, but since the measure "cuartil" is a measure, it does not allow me to use it as an axis, as I could do to have a column, that works like my "cuartil" measure?

Comment: Is it correct to assume you want to have some buckets (1P to 4P) to divide sites over? Actually, you are looking for: divide the sales in 4 equal parts?

Comment: Exactly, but when I do it with measure, I can not use that measure in a graph, because it can not be put as an axis, that's why I was looking for a way to find that partition in 4 equal parts, but to keep it in a column , and that it changes with respect to the region filter